# Safe to change char* function parameter to char const* in shared library function?

Tags: c

If I change an existing function in a shared library
`int some_function(char* some_string)`
to
`int some_function(char const* some_string)`
Is this a safe change? Will applications that use the library need re-linking or can I drop in a replacement .so file? The function body is not modified. The function does not modify `some_string`.

Comment: It's an API change, but not a breaking one. Code using the current API (with the non-const argument) should still work fine.

Comment: I guess ABI break depends on ABI. Which one(s) are you interested in, specifically? Though I doubt there is an ABI where `char*` and `const char*` are passed differently... But I don't think there's any guarantee.

Comment: API break this isn't, doing it the other way would be.

Comment: Also, double-check if ABI break really is an issue... And tell us which way is the concern for you (old app, new library or vice versa).

Comment: I'm not sure if ABI is the right term, I have rephrased the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four possible combinations:

1. Pointer to `char` parameter, passing pointer to `char`
2. Pointer to `char` parameter, passing pointer to `const char`
3. Pointer to `const char` parameter, passing pointer to `char`
4. Pointer to `const char` parameter, passing pointer to `const char`

This will break code only in case 2, and if the called function tries to write via the pointer<sup>*</sup>.

All other combinations are fine.

Actually, with the `const` at the parameter you put a constraint on the called function, not on the caller. With the `const` you assure the caller that the object at the pointer will not be modified.

---

*) Any serious compiler shall warn you if you do this. And the resulting program can crash on systems that take memory protection seriously. (For example, Win95 did not, and when we switched to Win2K and tried to `qsort()` a `const` array, we had a hard time to find the reason.)